# At most one record can be returned by this subquery. (Error 3354)

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi my query getting this error help me to recover it

```
SELECT CompanyId, CompanyName, RegistrationNumber,
  (select CompanyAddress from RPT_Company_Address where 
   RPT_Company_Address.CompanyId=Company.CompanyId) AS CompanyAddress, 
  MobileNumber, FaxNumber, CompanyEmail, CompanyWebsite, VatTinNumber
FROM Company;`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that your RPT_Company_Address table has more than one address for a given company.  If this should not be possible, you should try to correct the data and modify your schema to prevent the possibility of this happening.

On the other hand, if there can be multiple addresses, you must decide how your query should handle them:

1) Do you want the same company row listed multiple times-- one per each address?  If so, use an `INNER JOIN` to return them all:

```
SELECT Company.CompanyId, CompanyName, RegistrationNumber, CompanyAddress, ...
FROM Company
INNER JOIN RPT_Company_Address RCA ON RCA.CompanyId = Company.CompanyId
```

2) If you want only the first matching address, do a subquery on the first matching address corresponding to each company:

```
SELECT Company.CompanyId, CompanyName, RegistrationNumber, CompanyAddress, ...
FROM Company
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT CompanyId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1 PARTITION BY CompanyId) AS Num
    FROM RPT_Company_Address
) Addresses
    ON Addresses.ComapnyId = Company.CompanyId  
WHERE Num = 1
```

3) If you have some other way to identify the "primary" address that you want, include a `WHERE` clause with that criteria:

```
SELECT Company.CompanyId, CompanyName, RegistrationNumber, CompanyAddress, ...
FROM Company
INNER JOIN RPT_Company_Address RCA ON RCA.CompanyId = Company.CompanyId
WHERE RCA.PrimaryAddress = 1
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry am struggling with this query. 1st I have Company Table in that I create new query to take company id and company address and store separately as RPT_Company_Address. Now I created new query in that i took company name, registration number... from company table and address from RPT_Company_Address table. How i match this tables using company code, but am getting error.

Answer (score 7):

Your subquery below is returning more than one result

```
select CompanyAddress 
from RPT_Company_Address 
where RPT_Company_Address.CompanyId = Company.CompanyId
```

Therefore more than one address matches your company id.

Try fixing the data or using:

```
select top 1 CompanyAddress 
from RPT_Company_Address 
where RPT_Company_Address.CompanyId = Company.CompanyId
```

Comment: If i use top 1 then it show same address for all company ?

Comment: Using top 1 is a solution but not the best solution. You could have a problem where there are 2 addresses for one company, one addresses is correct and one is wrong. Top 1 does not guarantee that you will get the right address. The best thing to do is try and figure out why that sub query is bringing back multiple addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like your RPT_Company_Address table holds multiple entries for some CompanyIds.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question because I was also getting this error, "At most one record can be returned by this subquery." My answer will not apply to the stated question, but I'm providing it in case the solution I found will help others or myself in the future troubleshoot that error.

All three of the answers given in 2014 say that the error indicates that the table `RPT_Company_Address` contains more than one record with the same value of the field `CompanyId`. However, in my case the field in the role of `CompanyId` is set as an index with no duplicates, so it cannot possibly have the same value in more than one record.

To explain my situation and the solution I found, I will first reduce the questioner's code to the minimum relevant content by removing irrelevant fields:

```
SELECT 
  (select CompanyAddress from RPT_Company_Address 
   where RPT_Company_Address.CompanyId = Company.CompanyId) AS CompanyAddress
FROM Company;
```

However, in my case, I did not initially prefix the second occurrence of `CompanyId` with the table name  `Company`. Thus my initial code was like:

```
SELECT 
  (select CompanyAddress from RPT_Company_Address 
   where RPT_Company_Address.CompanyId = CompanyId) AS CompanyAddress
FROM Company;
```

And that apparently was the cause of the error. When I inserted the prefix `Company.` on the second occurrence of `CompanyId`, the error went away.

I don't know why the code without that second prefix made the subquery behave as if it was returning multiple values, or made Access think it was behaving that way, but inserting that prefix corrected the behavior.